# SQL Anywhere v10 Syntax error near OUTPUT

Tags: sqlanywhere

I'm attempting to output a table to an outside file. I've found a few questions regarding this and followed the answers from there without any luck.

`SELECT *
FROM transactions;
OUTPUT TO 'C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Test.txt'`

Is the statement I've been using, I've attempted different variations with formatting and file types such as .csv with no change.

Which produces:

ErrorCode : 102
SQLState  : 42W04
Message   : SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'OUTPUT' on line 1

SQL =

OUTPUT TO 'C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Test.txt'

Appreciate all your help

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this through dbisql, or in a different application? `OUTPUT TO` is a dbisql command, not a SQL statement recognized by the database server. You can use [the `UNLOAD` statement](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#1001/en/dbrfen10/rf-unload-statement.html) in any application to allow the server to create the file.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: I'm currently using DtSQL to connect to the DB, I'll give the UNLOAD a try. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like unload should work, thanks again. Just have to figure out how to get access to the `UNLOAD` statement