# How do I use OUTPUT TO in Sybase using C#

Tags: c#, sybase, sap-ase, sqlanywhere, nosql

I want to extract some tables from **Sybase** db using c# and currently I tried 
in sybase command and it works fine. but how Should I do this in c#?

```
SELECT * FROM users;
OUTPUT TO 'C:\\temp\\sample.sql' 
FORMAT TEXT
```

in **C#** I do like this.

```
 SAConnection myConnection = new SAConnection(connectionString);
 {
      myConnection.Open();
      SACommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
      myCommand.CommandText = @"select * from users  OUTPUT TO " + "'C:\temp\sample.sql'" + " FORMAT TEXT ";
      SADataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();                   
      myDataReader.Close();
      myConnection.Close();

 }
```

But I receive an error "Syntax Error near 'OUTPUT' at line 1.

Comment: are you exporting data into a .sql file? or .csv?

Comment: @JericCruz.  into a .sql file

Comment: Don't use Sybase DB, but one thing to check (not your error, but perhaps related) is that it looks like this code will run on the DB server using the DB's service account, rather than on your workstation using your own user account. Does the service account running the sybase process have access to that folder path?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  It doesn't  have any error in directory access  the only thing I think the wrong is the way I add the OUTPUT to in the command text. I don't  know how should I add that OUTPUT TO. to make it work.

Comment: are you extracting the table schema or the data? because you can do that in .csv for extracting data.

Comment: @JericCruz either way. .csv or .sql.  I would like to extract the table data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use `UNLOAD` statement `TO` `[filepath]`

```
myCommand.CommandText = @"UNLOAD SELECT * FROM users TO " + "'C:\temp\sample.sql'";
```

Note: the filepath must be in the sybase server file system and not in your application side.

e.g.

web server(your app) and database server(server where sybase in installed)

*if you set your filepath to `C:\sample.sql`, you get the file in your database server `C:\` directory and not in web server.*

you can refer to this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677756/sql-anywhere-v10-syntax-error-near-output) and [this document](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#1001/en/dbrfen10/rf-unload-statement.html)

> OUTPUT TO is a dbisql command, not a SQL statement recognized by the
>   database server.
>   -Graeme Perrow

Comment: I want to up vote it but I don't have enough reputation.